# Implementing perceptron function, getting TypeError: 'int object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python, machine-learning, perceptron

I am currently trying to manually implement a single layer perceptron in python, and am experiencing the following error but do not understand why.

Here is my code, and the data set that I used.

```
def predict(inVec, initWeights, bias):
    activation = bias;
    for i in range(len(inVec) - 1):
        activation += (initWeights[i] * inVec[i])
    return 1.0 if activation >= 0.0 else 0.0 

def updateWeights(inVec, weights, bias, learningRate):
    for row in inVec:
        target = row[-1]
        prediction = predict(row, weights, bias)
        error = target - prediction
        bias = bias + (learningRate*error)
        for i in range(len(row) -1):
            weights[i] = weights[i] + (learningRate*error) * row[i]
    return weights
```

Here is a sample data set:

```
dataset = [[10, 64.0277609352, 0], [15, 0.0383577812151, 0],[20, 22.15708796, 0],[25, 94.4005135336, 1],[30, 3.8228541672, 0],[35, 62.4202896763, 1]]
```

And here are the parameters of the function:

```
bias = 0
weights = [0,0]
learningRate = 0.01
```

I wish to execute the following function: `print(updateWeights(dataset, bias, weights, learningRate))`

But I keep receiving an error : `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` that points to the activation update part of the predict function. This is strange to me, because using that function alone, outside of the updateWeights function causes no error. Does anybody have thoughts on this?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/x/Documents/workspace/Machine Learning/Perceptron/perceptron.py", line 53, in <module>
    print(updateWeights(dataset, bias, weights, learningRate))
  File "/Users/x/Documents/workspace/Machine Learning/Perceptron/perceptron.py", line 24, in updateWeights
    prediction = predict(row, weights, bias)
  File "/Users/x/Documents/workspace/Machine Learning/Perceptron/perceptron.py", line 17, in predict
    activation += (initWeights[i] * inVec[i])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Post the *full stack trace*. But clearly, you are iterating over some iterable of `int`s, and then trying to index an `int`, which is throwing the error.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just added the the full stack traced, sorry about that.

Comment: ```print(updateWeights(dataset, bias, weights, learningRate))``` differs from your function-def. bias and weights are swapped. This results in wrong usage within predict too.

Comment: @sascha thank you, that solved the issue.